# Mapquest Open Javascript API addOptimizedRoute

Tags: javascript, mapquest

Due to the Mapquest changes to the API, I've had to switch from a community license to an open license, and I am using the 7.0.s library located on open.mapquestapi.com. When calling addOptimizedRoute, no route information is returned from the API. I have seen posts of a few other folks having the same issue, but no resolution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

One of the addresses I was testing with was able to be geocoded by the Enterprise gecoder, but not by the open geocoder. Once I had two addresses that were able to be mapped on the open data set, addOptimizedRoute() returns the expected routing info.